# How Can i change a Title Name with an Icon in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, event-handling, icons, title

Hello guys I got the following form in react :

```
 <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Row>
        <Form.Group as={Col} md="7" controlId="title">
          <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            name="title"
            placeholder="Title"
            value={title || ""}
            onChange={handleTitleChange}
            isInvalid={!title}
          />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">{!title}</Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form.Row>
```

and the following action:

```
const handleTitleChange = ev =>{
    setTitle(ev.target.value);
  if(ev.target.value === 'soccer') {
    setTitle(<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-football" />)
  } else if(ev.target.value === 'basketball') {
    setTitle(<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-basketball" />)
  }
  }
```

How can i Change the title saved from soccer to icon of a football? I mean when user write Soccer and save it instead of soccer i want to display a football

Comment: You can't display svg inside a text field

Comment: Try to conditionally render the input and svg icon based on `typeof title === "string"`

Comment: how am i supposed to do it? or change the Text field to svg when user saves the text Title

Comment: basically i want to change the Display. When user saves It displays Soccer word . I want to display a soccer ball

Comment: But then what happens to your text input when the icon is displayed ?

Comment: my TextInput saves in database . I got a function to getAll .  There i want to displaying instead of my textInput a soccerball if textInput ="soccer"